# Can I modify a value inside a BinaryHeap that isn't the top value?

Tags: rust, heap, priority-queue

Is there any way I can modify a value inside a Min-Heap that isn't the top, and have the heap updated to do so? Looking at the API, there doesn't seem to be any clear way to access these elements and invoke any type of update method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can modify a value inside a Min-Heap that isn't the top, and have the heap updated to do so?

You can modify values inside a Min-Heap, but no, the modification shall not alter the ordering of the item relatively to any other item in the `BinaryHeap`. Otherwise, the `BinaryHeap` will not be a max heap any more and there is no way to update it. You could convert the `BinaryHeap` to a sorted `Vec`, modify, re-sort, and convert the sorted `Vec` back into a `BinaryHeap`.

Example of how to modify elements inside a `BinaryHeap` without changing the relative order (full example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=66a2826b7713ed93cd9f7351b81457d7)):

```
struct Foo(i32, Cell<bool>);
impl Ord for Foo {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.0.cmp(&other.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bh = BinaryHeap::new();
    bh.push(Foo(0, Cell::new(true)));
    bh.push(Foo(1, Cell::new(false)));
    bh.push(Foo(2, Cell::new(false)));

    println!("{:?} => {:?}", bh, bh.peek());
    // prints: 
    // [..., Foo(1, Cell(false))] => Some(Foo(2, Cell(false)))

    // Modify `Foo(1, false)` to `Foo(1, true)`:
    for i in bh.iter() {
        if i.0 == 1 {
            i.1.set(true);
        }
    }

    println!("{:?} => {:?}", bh, bh.peek());
    // prints:
    // [..., Foo(1, Cell(true))] => Some(Foo(2, Cell(false)))
}
```

Here, `Foo`'s `Ord` implementation only depends on the value of first field (`i32`). That is, modifying the value of `Foo`'s second field (`bool`) does not change the ordering of any `Foo` relatively to any other `Foo`.

The requirements of `BinaryHeap` let us go one step further and also modify the first field of `Foo` as long as we don't change the ordering of any `Foo` relatively to any other `Foo` *in the `BinaryHeap`*. That is, we can change `Foo(0,..)` to `Foo(-3,..)` in this particular `BinaryHeap` without issues.

If the `BinaryHeap` were to contain a `Foo(-2,...)`, then changing `Foo(0,..)` to `Foo(-3,..)` would leave the `BinaryHeap` in an inconsistent state: it wouldn't be a max heap anymore. Still, note that no `unsafe` code is required anywhere to modify the elements of the `BinaryHeap`. That is, `BinaryHeap` upholds all safe Rust guarantees (no undefined behavior) even in the presence of "logic errors" that produce an inconsistent state.

What you can do instead is to convert the heap into a vector, modify it, and convert it back into the heap which will rebuild the whole heap ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=511646b459637ec8bb06c4baf08697d1)):

```
let mut bh = BinaryHeap::new();
bh.push(0);
bh.push(1);
bh.push(2);

println!("{:?} => {:?}", bh, bh.peek());

// convert into a vector:
let mut v = bh.into_vec();
println!("{:?}", v);

// modify in a way that alters the order:
v[1] = -1;
println!("{:?}", v);

// convert back into a binary heap
let bh: BinaryHeap<_> = v.into();
println!("{:?} => {:?}", bh, bh.peek());
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Looks like I need to implement my own version. :p

Comment: Note that you can go from `BinaryHeap` to a sorted `Vec` and back, so if you need to perform a modification, you could modify the sorted `Vec`, resort afterwards, and convert that back to a `BinaryHeap`.

Comment: Mhm I noticed that. The issue is the move operation for the benchmarks I'm doing can be expensive (at least that's how I assume ownership works with the into_vec function, still a rust beginner). I will keep this in mind in the future, already implemented my own though :p.

Answer (score 2):

> modify a value [...] and have the heap updated

No, the standard library's implementation of `BinaryHeap` does not allow adjusting any values that would require the heap ordering to change. The documentation even specifically [calls out interior mutability as a bad idea](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) (emphasis mine):

> It is a logic error for an item to be modified in such a way that the item's ordering relative to any other item, as determined by the `Ord` trait, changes while it is in the heap. This is normally only possible through **Cell, RefCell**, global state, I/O, or unsafe code.

There may be alternate implementations of binary heaps on crates.io, however.